# Compiz - don't raise window on click (while hold)

Tags: linux, window-manager, compiz

it seems that **Compiz** support forum is used for spam, and as I noticed similar questions answered here, I though it'd be best for me to ask here

I'm on **Ubuntu** 11.04 and window manager uses **Compiz**

While on **Windows** I got used to this feature which I'll try to explain:

Imagine simple drag&drop operation - I have *Explorer* maximized and I open *Notepad* on top of it. Now, if I click and hold mouse button on a file in *Explorer*, *Notepad* loses focus but it's still visible - *Explorer* window isn't raised over it, so I can finish my drag&drop operation. That's not happening on *Linux*, and I want to make it somehow.

In **Compiz** '*General options*' there are similar settings, but nothing can bring me this feature back. Sourced from Internet it seems also that **Openbox** window manager allows this feature while pressing *Super/Win* keyboard button.

So I want to know if this is somehow possible with **Compiz** or alternatively **Metacity**

(*I know that I can hover over taskbar window selector, then raise application and drop*)

Comment: Question is answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57752/dont-raise-window-on-click-while-hold

Answer (score 1):

There are many options:

- You can set *Notepad* (or whatever you're using) to be always on top,
- You can set *Explorer* (or whatever you're using) to be always on bottom,
- Don't fullscreen windows, so there's always a part of it visible, and just drag to that part.